# Deleting item after fade out vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

I'm working on simple Todo list app. When I click on X Id like to add a CSS class and after that Id like to delete that item with JavaScript; however, I want to wait for that animation to finish. My code looks like this:

```js
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    event.stopPropagation(); //stop bubbling effect
    this.parentElement.classList.add("fadeOut");
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.parentElement.remove(); //removing parent element with its contains
    }, 500)
  })
}
```

```html
<li><span>X</span> Go sleep </li>
```

But I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined at script.js:18` error. How do I pass that element I want to remove to function?

Comment: 'this' keyword , make your focus on to your setTimeout function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: You have to set a const for 'this' outside your settimeout function and use this const instead of 'this.'

Comment: Thank you Poorman it solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I ve declared const outside of the setTimeout function and it solved the problem, here is a code:

```
for(i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
spans[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    const el = this //Here I declare that constant
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.parentElement.classList.add("fadeOut");
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.parentElement.remove(); //removing parent element with its contains
    }, 500)
    
})}
```